# Need help converting Matlab's bsxfun to numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to convert a piece of MATLAB code, and this is a line I'm struggling with:

```
f = 0
wlab = reshape(bsxfun(@times,cat(3,1-f,f/2,f/2),lab),[],3)
```

I've come up with

```
wlab = lab*(np.concatenate((3,1-f,f/2,f/2)))
```

How do I reshape it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB

```
 reshape(x,[],3)
```

is the equivalent of `numpy`

```
 np.reshape(x,(-1,3))
```

the `[]` and `-1` are place holders for 'fill in the correct shape here'.

===============

I just tried the MATLAB expression is Octave - it's on a different machine, so I'll just summarize the action.

For `lab=1:6` (6 elements) the `bsxfun` produces a (1,6,3) matrix; the `reshape` turns it into (6,3), i.e. just removes the first dimension.  The `cat` produces a (1,1,3) matrix.

```
np.reshape(np.array([1-f,f/2,f/2])[None,None,:]*lab[None,:,None],(-1,3))
```

For `lab` with shape (n,m), the `bsxfun` produces a (n,m,3) matrix; the reshape would make it (n*m,3)

So for a 2d `lab`, the `numpy` needs to be

```
np.array([1-f,f/2,f/2])[None,None,:]*lab[:,:,None]
```

(In MATLAB the `lab` will always be 2d (or larger), so this 2nd case it closer to its action even if `n` is 1).

=======================

```
np.array([1-f,f/2,f/2])*lab[...,None]
```

would handle any shaped `lab`

If I make the Octave `lab` (4,2,3), the `bsxfun is also (4,2,3)

The matching numpy expression would be

```
In [94]: (np.array([1-f,f/2,f/2])*lab).shape
Out[94]: (4, 2, 3)
```

`numpy` adds dimensions to the start of the (3,) array to match the dimensions of `lab`, effectively

```
(np.array([1-f,f/2,f/2])[None,None,:]*lab) # for 3d lab
```

If `f=0`, then the array is `[1,0,0]`, so this has the effect of zeroing values on the last dimension of `lab`.  In effect, changing the 'color'.

Comment: Lab is actually the lab color space, so it's a 3 dimensional array.. Also, in MATLAB, f = 0, I think that bit of information is important, and should've been included in my question.

Comment: Am I right in thinking it would be np.array([1-f,f/2,f/2])[None,None,:]*lab[:,:,:] for a 3d array?

Comment: If `lab` last dimension is 3, and meant to match the array, the expression can be simplified, regardless of its dimensions.  See my edits.

Answer (score 6):

Not going to do it for your code, but more as a general knowledge:

`bsxfun` is a function that fills a gap in MATLAB that python doesn't need to fill: broadcasting.

Broadcasting is a thing where if a matrix that is being multiplied/added/whatever similar is not the same size as the other one being used, the matrix will be repeated.

So in python, if you have a 3D matrix `A` and you want to multiply every 2D slice of it with a matrix `B` that is 2D, you dont need anything else, python will broadcast `B` for you, it will repeat the matrix again and again. `A*B` will suffice. However, in MATLAB that will raise an error `Matrix dimension mismatch`. To overcome that, you'd use `bsxfun` as `bsxfun(@times,A,B)` and this will broadcast (repeat) `B` over the 3rd dimension of `A`.

This means that converting `bsxfun` to python generally requires nothing.

Comment: So, wlab = lab*(np.concatenate((3,1-f,f/2,f/2)))  is not required? Also, what about reshape? What's the empty matrix that's been given as the second parameter in MATLAB. How does that translate to numpy?

Comment: Seems like the first dimension is being reshaped automatically. How do I do that in numpy?

Comment: @stack https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html ?

Comment: @stack In general, try not to blindly trasnlate code. Understand what it does, and try to do that in Python.

Comment: I've already checked the docs, I'm unable to figure out how to make the first dimension shape automatically given the second dimension. The way it's done in MATLAB.

Comment: @stack you can do it manually really easily. you just need to divide the original size by 3.

Comment: I figured that much, but what if the number if not a multiple of the number of elements? In case of 25 elements, how would I do it? (x, 3), what would x be? How does MATLAB handle such cases? I don't have MTALAB so I'm having to ask these questions.

Comment: @stack Matlab crashes in those cases. You'd need to figure out what you need to do in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to

```
import numpy as np
wlab = np.kron([1-f,f/2,f/2],lab.reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: I assumed lab was a vector though, if matrix a slight modification can be made.

Comment: Lab is actually the lab color space, so it's a 3 dimensional array. Also, in MATLAB, f = 0, I think that bit of information is important, and should've been included in my question.

Comment: What would that modification be?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you use numpy you do not need to do any broadcasting, as this is done automatically for you.

For instance, looking at the following code should make it clearer:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 100]])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>>
>>> a
    array([[  1,   2,   3],
           [  3,   4,   5],
           [  6,   7,   8],
           [  9,  10, 100]])
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3])
>>>
>>> a - b
    array([[ 0,  0,  0],
           [ 2,  2,  2],
           [ 5,  5,  5],
           [ 8,  8, 97]])
>>>
```